# Breadcrumb elements aren't getting aligned to center

Tags: html, css, nav, breadcrumbs

I have used<center tag, text-align, margin 0 auto; and none of these options seem to work.

I have also tried div style="text-align:center;" just under  and before ol but it doesn't seem to work either.

The CSS for breadcrumb-campaign-background is as follows:

```css
.breadcrumb-campaign li {
  font-size: 14px !important; 
  margin: 0 auto; 
  text-align: center;
}

.breadcrumb-campaign-background {
  background-color: #111 !important; 
  margin-bottom: -70px; 
  margin-left: -15px;
}

.breadcrumb-campaign-background-first {
  background-color: #111 !important; 
  margin-left: 125px; 
  margin-bottom: -70px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container-700">
  <div class="maison breadcrumb-campaign container">
    <nav aria-label="breadcrumb">
      <ol class="breadcrumb breadcrumb-campaign-background" style="text-align: center">
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#stopcoopspying">Stop Co-op Spying</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#email">Email Co-Op Now</a></li>
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#take-action">Spread the Word</a></li>             
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#email">Take Action</a></li>   
        <li class="breadcrumb-item"><a href="#leaflet">Get the Leaflet</a></li>
      </ol>
    </nav>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your problem properlyUse the following code. Lmk if that works for you?

```
.breadcrumb-campaign li {
  font-size: 14px !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 20px 0px;
}
.breadcrumb-campaign li:not(:last-child)::after {
  /*   You may use arrow icon here */
  content: ">";
  margin: 0 5px;
}
```

Here's [Codepen link](https://codepen.io/dev-rahul/pen/vYrzrXq)